# Changing label color on validation error jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

Below is my code for view. i am basically validating checkbox if its checked on submit form. i want the color of checkbox text is to be red when its not checked while submitting a form. if someone checks it , it automatically comes to normal color. i know i can achieve it by putting checkbox click event but is this possible to have it inside validation?

**View**

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkterms" required/><span id="lblterms"> Please tick to confirm you have read, understood and agree to abide by our</span>@Html.ActionLink("Terms and Conditions", "TermsAndCondition", "SignupOrLogin", null, null)                                             
</div>
```

**Script**

```
  <script>

  $("#signupform").validate({
      rules: {
          password: { 
              required: true,
              minlength: 7,
              maxlength: 10,

          } , 

          confirmpassword: { 

              equalTo: "#password",
              minlength: 7,
              maxlength: 10                  
          }
      },

      groups: {
          birthday: "cmbDay cmbMonth cmbYear"
      },
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
          var name = element.prop("name");
          if (name === "cmbDay" || name === "cmbMonth" || name === "cmbYear") {
              error.insertAfter("");
          } 
          else if (name === "membershiptypelist") {
              error.insertAfter(""); //error will not be inserted e.g. This field is required.
          } 
          else if (name === "chkterms") {
              error.insertAfter(".terms-errors");                                    
              $('#lblterms').css('color', 'red');
          } 
          else {
              error.insertAfter(element);
          }
      }

  });
```

Comment: **Just use CSS**.  Since the plugin is automatically toggling the `error` class on the element as well as the label, you can use `input.error` and `label.error` for targeting them properly.